# Cannot initialize a variable of type 'void *' with an rvalue of type 'void *const *'

Tags: objective-c, c, core-audio, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to partially file a buffer in core-audio for iOS, in order to do this I need to change the start address I pass to memcpy.  My code looks like this...

```
UInt32 bytesToRead = inBuffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity;
int srcOffset = 0;
while (bytesToRead > 0) {
    UInt32 maxBytesFromCurrentPiece = self.currentAudioPiece.audioData.length - self.currentAudioPieceIndex;
    //Take the min of what the current piece can provide OR what is needed to be read
    UInt32 bytesToReadNow = MIN(maxBytesFromCurrentPiece, bytesToRead);

    NSData *subRange = [self.currentAudioPiece.audioData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(self.currentAudioPieceIndex, bytesToReadNow)];
    //Copy what you can before continuing loop

    void *srcStart = (&inBuffer->mAudioData + srcOffset);
    memcpy(srcStart, subRange.bytes, subRange.length);
    srcOffset += subRange.length;
    bytesToRead -= bytesToReadNow;
```

Appcode shows no error but the compiler shows this:

> "Semantic Issue" - Cannot initialize a variable of type 'void *' with
>   an rvalue of type 'void *const *'

On the line with "*srcStart".

Comment: What does the square bracket in this statement NSData *subRange = [self... mean?

Comment: That's an Objective-C message send expression, @Vlad. Most of the `.`s are too.

Comment: Why are you taking the address on `inBuffer` on that line?

Comment: How are `inBuffer` and `inBuffer->mAudioData` defined? Taking the address of the latter makes sense if it's an array, but not if it's a pointer

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
void *srcStart = (&inBuffer->mAudioData + srcOffset);
```

to

```
char *srcStart = ((char *)inBuffer->mAudioData) + srcOffset;
```

This will skip the appropriate number of bytes.